# Java factorial value changes when return is not 1

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, return

If the `if condition` return is something other 1, then the factorial value changes.

As I understand return is way to stop the program. But how is the `if statement return` is being involved with `factorial return` statement?

Here is the if condition:

```
    if (value == 1) {
       // return 0 will cause the factorial return to multiple by 0.
       // return 2 will cause the factorial return 48.
        return 1;  
    }
```

Final code:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(4));

    }

    private static int factorial(int value) {

        if (value == 1) {
           // return 0 will cause the factorial return to multiple by 0.
           // return 2 will cause the factorial return 48.
            return 1;  
        }

        return factorial(value - 1) * value;

    }

}
```

Comment: This is Java recursion . Check this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

If you return `2` for `factorial(1)` (which is incorrect),

you return `factorial(1) * 2 == 4` for `factorial(2)`

and you return `factorial(2) * 3 == 12` for `factorial(3)`

and you return `factorial(3) * 4 == 48` for `factorial(4)`.

As you can see, if you return an incorrect value at the end of the recursion, you'll get an overall incorrect result.

Since `factorial(1)` is equal to 1, you should return 1 when `value == 1`.

Comment: (Or return `1` for `factorial(0)`)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have some confusion related to Recursion concept.

Let's go through your code execution by execution, by taking example of value = 3.

Output should be 3! = 3 * 2 * 1 = 6

Now let's think how will you code work and why it should return 1 in If block.

1st execution factorial(3) => condition will fail, so it will return factorial(2) * 3;

2nd execution factorial(2) => condition will fail, so it will return factorial(1) * 2;

3rd execution factorial(1) => condition will pass, so it will return 1;

Now substitute those values in above,

factorial(1) = 1,

factorial(2) = 1 * 2

and factorial(3) = 1 * 2 * 3

So that's what we wanted.

Now imagine if you would return any other than 1, then output will change

ex. if we return 2, then 2 * 2 * 3 (not 3!)

I hope this helps you.